# Range query with ElasticSearch Simple Query String

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch Query String supports range queries, but it looks like the Simple Query String does not. 
How can I implement a search API that is built around the Simple Query String but also supports range queries?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html), the only option I see for numeric values (for example) is to write it out or to use prefixes (however, I haven't seen how to put a limit to the length):

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "2*|3*|4*",
        "fields": ["sample.TCPFlags"],
        "default_operator": "OR"
    }
  }
}
```

Apart from that, I haven't really found what you are asking for. For strings you may use the fuzziness operator syntax.

However, the is no direct equivalent of the range syntax as in the Query String... nevertheless, I hope that my answer does help you!

Comment: Hi Thomas unfortunately I see making this approach work difficult with date ranges. Also, ideally I would like to just grab the query provided by the user and pass it to Elastic without having to do much preprocessing